# Bootstrap 4 align-items-bottom inside div flexbox

Tags: flexbox, alignment, bootstrap-4

this is simple. I'm trying to align-items-bottom a gear svg image to the bottom center of a div. However, it always keeps at the top of the div.
I tried both align-items-center and also align-bottom options.

What happens
[image]

How it should be
[image]

```css
.gear {
  height: 50px;
 }
.banner {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid orange-bg banner d-flex justify-content-center align-items-bottom">
 <img class="gear d-flex" src="/assets/gear.svg">
</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `align-items-bottom` class. The class name is  `align-items-end`..

```
<div class="container-fluid orange-bg banner d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
        <img class="gear d-flex" src="//placehold.it/300x70">
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ub6hNpd9TL

Answer (score 1):

Rows and column are your friends in Bootstrap.

So, create a pair, put your image/SVG inside, apply the class `d-flex` to the column and `mt-auto` (margin-top:auto) to the image.

Click the "run code snippet" button below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-warning banner d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="row" style="height: 60px;">
           <div class="col d-flex">
               <img class="gear mt-auto" src="https://placehold.it/30">
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```